# Segmentation fault in c in my code.

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, command-prompt

I am creating a simple unix shell using c. Where there are two commands: "set prompt" which changes the user prompt and "quit" which exits the program, any other commands are taken care of by the system. I have the following code but I keep getting segmentation fault. What is it that I am accessing incorrectly. Please Help.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char cmdLine[BUFSIZ];
    char *cmdPrompt = "$PROMPT:";
    {
        if(argc!=1)
        {
            printf("error: Incorrect number of arguments on command line");
        }
        else
        {
            while(1) //This creates an infinite loop as 1 will never be equals 0
            {
                printf("%s", cmdPrompt);                    //Prints the current Prompt on the screen
                fgets(cmdLine, sizeof(cmdLine), stdin);     //puts the user input into the cmdLine array
                char *token = strtok(cmdLine, " \n");        //tokenizes the user input with delimitters space or enter

                if(strcasecmp(token, "QUIT")==0)            //checks if the user input is "quit"
                {
                    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);                     //successfully exits program
                }
                else if(strcasecmp(token, "SET")==0)        //checks if the first part of user input is "set"
                {
                    token = strtok(NULL, " \n");             
                    if(strcasecmp(token, "PROMPT")==0)      //checks to see if the next part is promt
                    {
                        token = strtok(NULL, "\n");         
                        cmdPrompt = token;                  //changes the user prompt
                    }
                else
                    {
                        system(cmdLine);                    //all other commands taken care of by the system
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you said "Segmentation fault" that would probably imply you are on some sort of *nix system. If that is the case I recommend compiling your `c` files with `-g` to enable debugging. With any luck `gdb` (the debugger) is on your system and you can launch it with `gdb ./nameofprog` . It should stop when it hits a segfault and tell you where.

Comment: thanks for the help, but seems there was just a problem with my compiler

Answer (score 1):

From the manual page (`man strtok` in a Unix shell):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> The strtok() and strtok_r() functions return a pointer to the next token, or NULL if there are no more tokens.

Which means you need to make sure that the returned value (`token`) is not a NULL pointer before using it.

Also the `system()` call may not like it if the `cmdLine` variable includes a `'\n'` character.

Also, fgets() can return NULL on errors:

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> gets() and fgets() return s on success, and NULL on error or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read.

You should be fine on that one though.

Comment: thanks for the help, but seems there was just a problem with my compiler